# How to center text on multiple row within table?

Tags: tables, cell

I have produced the following table:
[image: Table]

By using the following code:

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
      \caption{Dati principali del velivolo \texttt{Lockheed C-130J Hercules}.}
    \begin{tabular}{lccl}
     \toprule
     Tipologia di dato & Grandezza & Simbolo & Valore   \\
    % \multicolumn{4}{c}{Simulation time \SI{30}{\second}}\\
      \midrule
      \multirow{3}*{\shortstack{Geometria}} & Superficie alare & $S$ & \SI[]{162.12}{\meter\squared} \\
       &Apertura alare& $b$&     \SI{40.41}{\meter}\\ 
       &Allungamento alare& $\AR$&   \num{10.07}\\ 
     \midrule
     \multirow{6}*{\shortstack{Aerodinamica}} & Fattore di Oswald & $e$ & \num{0.95} \\
      & Coefficiente di resistenza parassita &$C_{D_0}$& \num{0.020}\\ 
      & Angolo di portanza nulla & $\alpha_{ZL}$ & \SI[]{-2.86}{\deg}  \\
       & Gradiente retta di portanza &$C_{L_\alpha}$& \SI[]{5.73}{deg^{-1}}\\ 
        & Coefficiente di portanza max  &$C_{L_{max}}$& \num[round-precision = 4]{1.0861}\\ 
         & Velocità di stallo a SL  &$V_{stall}$& \SI[per-mode = symbol]{51.4}{\meter\per\second}\\ 
         \midrule
         \multirow{4}*{\shortstack{Propulsione}} & Potenza totale motori (4) &$P_{tot}$& \SI[]{10304.8}{\kilo\watt}\\ 
         & Rendimento propulsore &$\eta$& \num{0.93}\\ 
         & consumo specifico per\\ & unità di spinta &$TSFC$& \SI[per-mode=symbol]{1.31e-5}{\kilo\gram\per\newton\per\second}\\ 
         \midrule
         \multirow{3}*{\shortstack{Limiti strutturali}} & Carico alare max &$(L/S)_{max}$& \SI[per-mode=symbol]{433.7}{\kilo\gram _f\per\meter\squared}\\ 
        & Portanza strutturale max &$S (L/S)_{max}$& \SI[]{70311}{\kilo\gram\-f}\\ 
        & Velocità strutturale max (@ 3050 m) &$V_{NE}$& \SI[per-mode=symbol]{194.46}{\meter\per\second}\\ 
        \midrule
         \multirow{4}*{\shortstack{Masse (kg)}} & Peso operativo a vuoto &$OEW$& \num{34274}\\  
         & Peso max al decollo &$MTOW$& \num{68976}\\ 
         & Peso paylaod max &$m_{payload\max}$& \num{18955 }\\ 
         & Peso combustibile max&$m_{fuel\max}$& \num{29325 }\\ 
         \midrule
         \multirow{2}*{\shortstack{Prestazioni generali}} & Velocità di crociera max (@ 8535 m) &$V_{cruise\ max}$& \SI[per-mode=symbol]{194.46}{\meter\per\second}\\ & rateo di virata max (@ SL) &$\delta_{turn\ max}$& \SI[per-mode=symbol]{4.3}{\deg\per\second}\\ 
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
 \label{tab:Q6:data c130}
\end{table}
```

I want to center the words circled in red on the row delimited by the red lines.
Can you help me?

Comment: Please provide a bit more information about your document setup. E.g., how or where is `\AR` defined? How wide is the textblock?

Comment: I use the following structure:
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}

Comment: Please also reveal how or where `\AR` is defined and how wide the textblock is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "look" of the table shown in your screenshot is rather busy -- so busy, in fact, that it risk causing a distraction from the table's contents.

I would therefore like to suggest that you change the table layout, mainly by left-aligning all cells and by using automatic line breaking and hanging indentation in the second column. This may be achieved in a straightforward way by employing a `tabularx` column and applying hanging indentation. (If the margins are 2.5cm wide and Computer Modern fonts are in use, 4 cells in column 2 will experience an automatic line break.) Replacing some of the `\midrule` directives with `\addlinespace` also helps create a less-busy, and more open, "look".

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters as needed
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,tabularx,ragged2e,amsmath}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hangafter=1\hangindent=1.5em}X}
\newcommand\vn[1]{\mathrm{#1}} 
\providecommand\AR{\vn{AR}} % ??

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Dati principali del velivolo \texttt{Lockheed C-130J Hercules}.\strut}
\label{tab:Q6:data c130}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} lLll @{}}
\toprule
Tipologia di dato & Grandezza & Simbolo & Valore   \\
\midrule
Geometria
    & Superficie alare   & $S$   & \SI{162.12}{\meter\squared} \\
    & Apertura alare     & $b$   & \SI{40.41}{\meter}\\ 
    & Allungamento alare & $\AR$ & \num{10.07}\\ 
\addlinespace
Aerodinamica
   & Fattore di Oswald & $e$ & \num{0.95} \\
   & Coefficiente di resistenza parassita &$C_{D_0}$& \num{0.020}\\ 
   & Angolo di portanza nulla & $\alpha_{\vn{ZL}}$ & \SI{-2.86}{\deg}  \\
   & Gradiente retta di portanza &$C_{L_\alpha}$& \SI{5.73}{deg^{-1}}\\ 
   & Coefficiente di portanza max  &$C_{L_{\max}}$& \num[round-precision = 4]{1.0861}\\ 
   & Velocità di stallo a SL  &$V_{\vn{stall}}$& \SI[per-mode = symbol]{51.4}{\meter\per\second}\\ 
\addlinespace
Propulsione
   & Potenza totale motori (4) &$P_{\vn{tot}}$& \SI{10304.8}{\kilo\watt}\\ 
   & Rendimento propulsore &$\eta$& \num{0.93}\\ 
   & Consumo specifico per unità di spinta &$\vn{TSFC}$ & \SI{1.31e-5}{\kilo\gram\per\newton\per\second}\\ 
\addlinespace
Limiti strutturali
   & Carico alare max &$(L/S)_{\max}$           & \SI{433.7}{\kilo\gram _f\per\meter\squared}\\ 
   & Portanza strutturale max &$S (L/S)_{\max}$ & \SI{70311}{\kilo\gram\-f}\\ 
   & Velocità strutturale max (@~3050 m) &$V_{\vn{NE}}$ & \SI{194.46}{\meter\per\second}\\ 
\addlinespace
Masse (kg)
   & Peso operativo a vuoto &$\vn{OEW}$ & \num{34274}\\  
   & Peso max al decollo &$\vn{MTOW}$   & \num{68976}\\ 
   & Peso paylaod max &$m_{\textrm{payload max}}$  & \num{18955 }\\ 
   & Peso combustibile max&$m_{\textrm{fuel max}}$ & \num{29325 }\\ 
\addlinespace
Prestazioni generali
   & Velocità di crociera max (@~8535 m) & $V_{\textrm{cruise max}}$    & \SI{194.46}{\meter\per\second}\\ 
   & Rateo di virata max (@~SL)          & $\delta_{\textrm{turn max}}$ & \SI{4.3}{\deg\per\second}\\ 
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```